# Cognito Forms: output formatting

Tags: cognito-forms

Ok, I've got a small problem.  We use a Cognito form to gather data from techs in the field doing internet installations.  When they submit their form responses we display their form submission to them and they copy and paste that into another tool required by our client.

The output of the Cognito form puts the questions on one line and the answer on the next line.  That format bothers some of the folks reading the output.  Is there a way to have the form put the answers on the same line with the questions?

Answer (score 2):

One thing that you could do is add a second page to your form that is only visible when the Entry is submitted. On the second page can be a copy-friendly summary of all of the information in calculation fields.

You can use this template as a reference: https://www.cognitoforms.com/templates/shared/None440/Summary

Keep in mind that the Preview option for this will not show the finished product. You will actually need to submit a sample entry to see how the summary will look on the confirmation page!